# How do I execute SELECT dateTime FROM TABLE_NAME using greendao

Tags: android, database, greendao

How do I execute `SELECT dateTime FROM TABLE_NAME` using greendao.

I am trying to fetch the coulmn datetime from table "TABLE_NAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch a single column you need to use a raw query

```
private static final String SQL_DISTINCT_DATE = "SELECT DISTINCT "+YourDao.Properties.EName.datetime+" FROM "+YourDao.TABLENAME;

public static List<String> listEName(DaoSession session) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = session.getDatabase().rawQuery(SQL_DISTINCT_DATE, null);
    try{
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                result.add(c.getString(0));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```